Selenium DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist | chrome not reachable
I've tried to resolve the problem every single one option, but nothing:

chrome --version: Google Chrome for Testing 131.0.6778.85

chromedriver --version: ChromeDriver 131.0.6778.85

Selenium -v: 4.27.1

Pytest: 8.3.3

Python -v: 3.10


from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def test_first_check_the_access():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1024,768")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/home/me/foo')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')

    #chrome_options.binary_location = "/usr/local/bin/chrome"
    #service = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

    assert "Google" in driver.title

    driver.quit()

result after docker-compose exec test-runner pytest tests/test_1.py:
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
E         (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
E         (The process started from chrome location /usr/local/bin/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

FAILED tests/test_1.py::test_first_check_the_access - selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally. 

Dockerfile:

FROM python:3.10-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    wget \
    gnupg \
    unzip \
    libglib2.0-0 \
    libnss3 \
    libgconf-2-4 \
    libfontconfig1 \
    libx11-xcb1 \
    libxcomposite1 \
    libxcursor1 \
    libxdamage1 \
    libxrandr2 \
    libgbm1 \
    libasound2 \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    libxss1 \
    libxtst6 \
    xdg-utils \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ARG CHROMIUM_VERSION="latest"

RUN wget -P /tmp https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/131.0.6778.85/linux64/chrome-linux64.zip \
    && unzip /tmp/chrome-linux64.zip -d /tmp/ \
    && mv /tmp/chrome-linux64/chrome /usr/local/bin/ \
    && rm -rf /tmp/chrome-linux64.zip

RUN wget -P /tmp https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/131.0.6778.85/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip \
    && unzip /tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip -d /tmp/ \
    && mv /tmp/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/ \
    && rm -rf /tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chrome \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

EXPOSE 4444

COPY . .

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]

Docker-compose, connection with selenium exists:

version: '3.8'

networks:
  web:
    driver: bridge

services:
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    networks:
      - web
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    environment:
      - SE_NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=1
      - SE_NODE_MAX_SESSION=1
      - DISPLAY=:99
      - VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1
      - VNC_WIDTH=1920
      - VNC_HEIGHT=1080
      - VNC_COL_DEPTH=24

    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm

  test-runner:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    networks:
      - web
    entrypoint: ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
    depends_on:
      - selenium

I try to resolve the problem, with Selenium webdriver.Chrome about a week, but every combination of options just doesn't work.
The test is working after i try to execute it without docker-compose exec.
And if i'll try to paste the: options=chrome_options into webdriver.Chrome() it'll show me this:
E       selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
E         (chrome not reachable)
E         (The process started from chrome location /usr/local/bin/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

FAILED tests/test_1.py::test_first_check_the_access - selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally. 

which means exactly 232: SessionNotCreatedException as upper-one.
